# Create SOAP XML REQUEST from selected dataframe columns in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to create an XML SOAP REQUEST by extracting a few columns from each row of a dataframe ? 10 records in a dataframe means 10 separate SOAP XML REQUESTs.

How would you make the function call using map now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by applying a [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) function to the dataframe.

```
val df = your dataframe
df.map(x => convertToSOAP(x))

// convertToSOAP is your function.
```

Putting up an example based on your comment, hope you find this useful.

```
case class emp(id:String,name:String,city:String)
val list = List(emp("1","user1","NY"),emp("2","user2","SFO"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)
val df = rdd.toDF
df.map(x => "<root><name>" + x.getString(1) + "</name><city>"+ x.getString(2)  +"</city></root>").show(false)

// Note: x is a type of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Output will be as follows :

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|value                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|<root><name>user1</name><city>NY</city></root>    |
|<root><name>user2</name><city>SFO</city></root>   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Edited my question with the convertToSOAP function. Unfortunately this is the closest I could get to fetch the XML tag values and the map function does not fit well here.

Comment: Why do you think map does not fit well here. w.r.t. code you added, I think it looks alright unless you want to use SOAP library to build soap message. Why do you think it is not efficient ?

Comment: It is efficient. But my method expects a Dataframe and x would be of type Row. If I change definition of my method, then I will not be able to select columns from it. That is why, I am unable to match my method with your map suggestion. May be you can guide on how to reframe my method in your suggestion lines.

Comment: oh okay. You do not have to pass the DataFrame to your function. You could retrieve all the data you need to build the SOAP request and pass it to the function as a String.

Comment: How would you achieve this function call using map now?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code sample, see if it helps you.

Comment: Hey, did that help you ?

Comment: On the first few attampts, it dint. x.getString(1) was giving issues. I have parked this for a couple days.